# Xcode 7, prepareForSegue error in SWIFT: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am attempting to segue from one TableViewController to another, but I'm getting the following runtime error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier reuseIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Here's my Storyboard: 
[image]

Here is my code in the first TableViewController in the above:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

    let tableEntry = data[indexPath.row]
    let rowImage = UIImage(named: tableEntry.imageFilename)

    cell.mainCellImage?.image = rowImage
    cell.mainCellLabel?.text = tableEntry.heading

    cell.mainCellImage.layer.opacity = 1
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return cell
}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MainToFamily") {

        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? FamilyTableViewController {


            if let mainIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

                //passes the index (i.e. table row) selected to the next view controller so that we know what new data to pull
                destination.selectedIndex = mainIndex

            }


        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've clearly set the cell reuse identifier for the first table view, but have you done so for the second one? Based on what you've shown it looks like the exception is being thrown when the second table view loads

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thank you.  The second TableViewController did not have an identifier set for the prototype cell.